# Wpf ItemsControl with datatemplate, problem with doubled border for some items

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, border, itemscontrol, textblock

I have simple ItemsControl with custom datatemplate, template contains only textblock with border. All items should be displayed vertically one after another, but some items have extra border. 
How can I remove it?

I want to achieve something similar to enso launcher, it looks like
[image]

My implementation looks like this

[image: wpf textblock with border]

here is my xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="winmole.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    x:Name="hostWindow"
    Height="Auto"
    MinHeight="100"
    MinWidth="100"
    Width="Auto"
    Padding="10"
    AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent"
    Top="0"
    Left="0"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    Topmost="True"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    KeyUp="Window_KeyUp" 
    >
<Window.Resources>

    <!--Simple data template for Items-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="itemsTemplate">
        <Border Background="Black" Opacity="0.9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CornerRadius="0,2,2,0">
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Title}" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 FontFamily="Georgia" FontSize="30" 
                 Height="Auto"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 TextAlignment="Left" Padding="5" Margin="0" Foreground="Yellow"/>

        </Border>

    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>

    <ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="itcPrompt"  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=hostWindow, Path=DataItems}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemsTemplate}"  >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>

</DockPanel>
```

Comment: It appears all items have a border; what do you mean in that "some" of the items have an extra border?

Comment: in this example all items have a border, but when i display folders from c:\ drive there are some items which doesn't have this border. Anyway how to remove this border?

Comment: When I change TextBlock to Label problem has disappeard. Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Are you talking about the "lines" that appear between the items? In that case, setting UseLayoutRounding="True" or SnapToDevicePixels="True" will get rid of them. Updated my answer

Comment: SnapToDevicePixesl do the job! Great, thanks @Meleak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: Try to set `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` on the Border

```
<Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Black" Opacity="0.9" ...
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't worked. I have edit my question and add what my goal is. Maybe someone knows different way to implement it

Comment: hmm, I have copy and paste your code and it isn't working for me, both UseLayoutRounding="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" give the same results. But thanks for help.

Comment: as you wrote in previous comment set SnapToDevicePixels="True" for Border solved my problem

Comment: @ksirg: Ok, glad that one did it! I'll update my answer with SnapToDevicePixels instead :)